# how to hide columns of antd data table for small devices(mobile view)?

Tags: antd

If the table has five columns i want to display only 2 columns for mobile view

https://ant.design/components/table

Answer (score 0):

you can keep columns in component state and dynamically filter the columns on window resize. Something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener("resize", <callback function to update columns>);

 // cleanup
 return() => window.removeEventListener("resize");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside render method you need to declare columns with **let** and change them **if window.innerWidth < 480** (I made it less then 500 px to be safe). By changing, I mean **filtering** from an array of columns only those columns that you want. The best way to filter is by key, because it's unique. This is how the code looks in react:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";

export default class MainPage extends PureComponent {
  renderMobileTable = columns => {
    return columns.filter(
      column => column.key === "name" || column.key === "city"
    );
  };
  render() {
    const dataSource = [
      {
        key: "1",
        name: "Mike",
        lastName: "Willins",
        age: 32,
        address: "10 Downing Street",
        city: "Chicago"
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        name: "John",
        lastName: "Billards",
        age: 42,
        address: "5th Blvd",
        city: "New York"
      }
    ];

    let columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name"
      },
      {
        title: "Last Name",
        dataIndex: "lastName",
        key: "lastName"
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age"
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address"
      },
      {
        title: "City",
        dataIndex: "city",
        key: "city"
      }
    ];
    const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 500;
    if (isMobile) {
      columns = this.renderMobileTable(columns);
    }
    return <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
  }
}
```

For the source code you may refer to my [repository](https://github.com/Loratadin/antd-features) on GitHub.

NOTE: if you are testing mobile view in Chrome Dev Tools, make sure you reload the page after resizing, as we put the logic into render method and the application has to be re-rendered or reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In antd v4 you can use column prop 'responsive'

```js
const columns = [{
    title: 'identification number',
    dataIndex: 'ID',
    responsive: ['sm'],
}]
```

https://ant.design/components/table/#Column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to hide columns on a mobile view. An alternative solution: Just add `x` scrollbar to the table:

```
<Table scroll={{ x: "max-content" }} />
```

By adding this, the table will only take up the necessary width and a `x` scrollbar will appear for users to scroll horizontally through the table on smaller devices.